# How to implement SAML in python flask application running on GAE

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, authentication, single-sign-on, saml

Can anyone explain the steps to implement SAML SSO for a python application running on GAE, the user need to access the GCP Bigquery through the application. The users have the organizational credentials, I am developer does not have the G-Suite access.